# Image resize handles in IE's contenteditable mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How can I selectively turn off image resize handles in IE 7+'s contenteditable mode?  I've tried setting the image's contentEditable to false and its onresizestart to "return false" to no avail.

I'm using tinyMCE.

Comment: Possibly related (but not exact dupe as I thought at first)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926525/removing-resize-handlers-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: Yes, that refers to FireFox only.

Comment: Does the image still need to be changeable and generally behave like an image?

Comment: The answer by Teemu worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Set [`unselectable="on"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your images. Works for older IEs, but is lately deprecated.

Comment: $('<div/>',{'unselectable':'on'}); which should be the same as  <div unselectable="on"> works for me in explorer

Comment: This... sort of works for me? It renders the image unresizable, but the first click after loading the page still brings up the resize handles, and prevents correct function of click events. If I then click outside the image, the resize handles are cleared - but only if I don't click another image, then the handles stay present on the image they appeared on first! This confuses me somewhat.

I use jQuery.

Comment: @GertSønderby Looks like `unselectable` is deprecated in IE10, maybe 9 too. Anyway, it's not in the documentation, but I'd recall this needs to be set as an attribute, setting a property doesn't work.

Comment: @Teemu, thank's for this solution. However, there is one problem regarding it. When you set `unselectable` -> `on`, it makes the `element` `unresizeable`. The handles are visible on the first click, but if you click the element again they won't appear. The problem is, one can't dragNdrop the element within the `contenteditable` area. Is there a way to make it `draggable` in IE as well? **A side note:** - > `unselectable` works even in `IE11` if it is set via `setAttribute` -> `element.setAttribute('unselectable','on')`.

Comment: @W.D. When `unselectable` is set to an element, it should really be unselectable, hence not possible to make it draggable either. I can't reproduce the first-click issue in IE11, though a deprecated property may behave oddly.

Comment: @Teemu, I was asking whether it is possible to disable image resizing in `IE11` inside a `contenteditable` element, but at the same time make it draggable? The way I know of (`onresizestart`) is not supported as of `IE11`, thus using `element.onresizestart = function(){return false;}` doesn't work in the aforementioned browser, but it does work in older versions of `IE`.

Comment: @W.D. Well, this actually is not related to my answer then : ). Please ask a new question about the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the [advimagescale](http://code.google.com/p/tinymce-plugin-advimagescale/) plugin in tinyMCE to stop all images from being resized.
However, I found it stopped images from being dragged and dropped into an editor instance.

I found I could strip the size attributes on mouseup using:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onMouseUp.add(function(ed, e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName == "IMG") {
            e.target.removeAttribute("width"); 
            e.target.removeAttribute("height"); 
        }
    });
}
```

I would dearly love to get rid of those damn handles though.

Answer (score 2):

This took pain, time and luck to find: You want the 'controlselect' event to remove the resize handles in IE.

```
element.oncontrolselect = function () { return false; };
```

The above line of code worked for me (caveat: Not using TinyMCE, but then, this seems to be a contentEditable headache, not a specific TinyMCE one). You need to set this handler on any element you want to not have these drag handles (in my case, images).

Comment: As of IE11, this method does not work any more - and it does not appear any other does either.

Comment: @Gert What version of windows? It works for me on 8.0 and 8.1

Comment: I was using 8.1 at the time, from modern.ie. I admit, I haven't checked this since, assuming that A) things were terrible and B) they were not going to be fixed - but I'm prepared to be positively surprised. :-)

Comment: I'm seeing the same on Win7 / IE11 -- no `controlselect` event is being fired, and the ugly boxes are still there.

Comment: Well... maybe Edge will have something?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the **function** of the handles by defining a behaviour file. I couldn't find anything which would let you hide the handles. The result of the code below is that dragging the handles has no effect.

noresize.htc:

```
<public:component lightweight="true">

    <script language="javascript">

    function CancelEvent()
    {
            return false ;
    }

this.onresizestart = CancelEvent ;
this.onbeforeeditfocus = CancelEvent ;

</script>

</public:component>
```

Then in css:

```
img.noresize {
    behaviour:url(/css/noresize.htc);
}
```

Note that you'll need to get that url() path right. Add the css class to the images you want to selectively disable.

This article has an alternative .htc file which didn't work for me:

http://nickw101.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/disabling-image-resizing-in-ie-contenteditable-elements/

Comment: (This has unfortunately stopped working since IE11.)

Answer (score 1):

Just the best fix ever:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <label contenteditable="false"><input/></label>
</div>
```

or any html element that wraps your input/img

Works like a charm on IE11 with img too.

Answer (score 0):

Often you will not want the resize functionnality for any element to be accessible. You can set the `onresizestart` handler of the `contenteditable` **container** so it cancels any resize.
That is:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" onresizestart="return false;">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Or with JS:

```
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
editor.onresizestart=function(){return false;}
```

That will not hide the handles but the users will not be able to resize the element, whatever type it is.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The onresizestart="return false;" does not work in IE 11