# How to Remove Resize handles and border of div with contentEditable and size style

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, contenteditable

The problem I'm having is with the contentEditable attribute in IE. 
The problem is that I'm getting resize handles, and a thick border around  elements when they're in focus. The styles for with, height and display are needed.
Any idea of how to remove them? CSS or Javascript

A simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div contentEditable="true" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: table" >
<div contentEditable="true" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: table-cell">
<p>aaa</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926525/removing-resize-handlers-on-contenteditable-div ?

Comment: The with and height style are needed, so it is not the same with the above question. Besides, only disable resize handle is not accepted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable elements selection and resizing in contenteditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864047/how-to-disable-elements-selection-and-resizing-in-contenteditable-div)

Answer (score 1):

Do You need contentEditable="true" defined twice ? 
If You delete the first one, the resize handles go away, although the functionality remains.

http://jsfiddle.net/2uphD/1/

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap the outer div with contenteditable value as false to take away the resize handles. Below the the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uphD/192/)

```html
<div>
<div contentEditable="false" style="width:50%; height:50%; display:table" >
    <div contentEditable="true" style="width:50%; height:50%; display:table-cell" >  
        <p>div1</p> 
    </div>  
</div>

<div contentEditable="false" style="width:50%; height:50%; display:table" >
    <div contentEditable="true" style="width:50%; height:50%; display:table-cell" >  
        <p>div2</p> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just should use **resize: none** for disable handlers:

```
<div 
  contenteditable
  style="max-height:200px;resize: none">
</div>
```

And this style to disable border on focus:

```
<style>
[contenteditable]:focus {
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
</style>
```