# How to disable elements selection and resizing in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, contenteditable

E.g. I have the following layout:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   <span class="text-block" contenteditable="false">
      <span contenteditable="false">Name</span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <i class="small-icon-remove"></i>
      </a>
   </span>
​</div>
```

So, how to disable this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible if you've made your span non-editable.

Comment: i cant reproduce this issue in ie11 from the html element you provided, but i had the same issue in my application due to contenteditable attribute

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I spent on this a lot of time myself, when trying to completely hide control selections (this is how they are called) in [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com)'s [widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro). Unfortunately I don't have a good news.

### Solution 1

First of all, there's a [`mscontrolselect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event. When I found it (and the fact that its name has an `ms` prefix) I was very happy, because [according to MS](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/791253/ie-11-enableobjectresizing-execcommand-support) it should be preventable.

But it turned out that it's totally unstable. Sometimes it is fired, sometimes it isn't. It varies between IEs versions, DOM structure, attributes, which element you click, is it a block element, etc. The usual MS's crap. But you can try:

```
function controlselectHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}
document.body.addEventListener('mscontrolselect', controlselectHandler);
```

However, this will completely block selection (if it worked). So you'll make those elements unselectable at all.

### Solution 2

Then there's a second option, more reliable - moving selection somewhere else after such element was clicked. There are few ways this can be implemented. In CKEditor we're fixing selection on `mousedown`... and `mouseup` because (again) sometimes it's not enough for IE and it depends on dozen of conditions. You could also listen to `selectionchange` event and fix selection there.

However, again, we're also talking about blocking selection of such element.

### Solution 3

Therefore, the third option is to block not selection, but the `resizestart` event. CKEditor combines this with `enableObjectResizing` command: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/a81e759/plugins/wysiwygarea/plugin.js#L211-L218. This solution will prevent resizing, but of course will not hide those ugly borders.

### Solution 4

As I mentioned, I worked on this problem in CKEditor. We managed to make it possible to have non-editable elements inside editable, but with completely controllable and unified behaviour between browsers. The complete solution is too complex to be explained on StackOverflow and it took us months to implement it. We called this feature widgets. See some [demos here](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets). As you can see there are no control selection when non-editable element is selected. The selection appears on a short moment only between `mousedown` and `mouseup`, but only in specific cases. Except for that everything works as it would be native (although it's a completely fake thing).

Read more in the [Introduction to Widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets) and in the [Widgets Tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro).

Answer (score 11):

This post was critical when solving this issue for me (works in tinyMCE):

[How to Remove Resize handles and border of div with contentEditable and size style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772342/how-to-remove-resize-handles-and-border-of-div-with-contenteditable-and-size-sty][1])

By placing a contenteditable DIV within a non contenteditable DIV the handles do not appear in IE or FF but you can still edit the content

Ex.

```
<div class="outerContainer" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="innerContainer" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just spent several days looking into this and this solution is by far the cleanest, easiest and cross compatible.  It doesn't attempt to override any of the browser's default behavior by capturing mouse or select events like some of the other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for this. In TinyMCE's inline editor, this only seems to work on the whole editor, but now I am still seeing the outline and resizable corners on the individual elements (i.e. <p>) inside the contenteditable=true div.

Comment: Yes it hides the border but it restricts the arrow key navigation only to tat block. https://jsfiddle.net/rex3c3yf/2/ Any help on solving this

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 5**

When the focus is moved to child control change the content editable element attribute value to false and same way once your focus leaves from child control again set the content editable to true.

Answer (score 5):

To disable the resize handles, all I had to do was add the following for IE11:

```
div {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

For firefox executing this line after the contenteditable element has been inserted works:

```
document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

What solved the problem for me was removing a `max-width: 100% !important;` line from the CSS properties of the DOM elements within the `contenteditable` DIV. Hope it helps!

BTW this does not happen on MS Edge... fingers crossed that this shows a movement in the right direction by MS :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It appears that from previous posts here there are certain behaviors that IE recognizes and will add this paragraph focus/resize. For me it was because I had a style for paragraphs within the contenteditible div.

Removing:

```
div[contenteditble="true"] p{
   min-height:1em;
}
```

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow:hidden` also can cause this issue, like:

```
ul, ol {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
On placing the non content-editable span within a content-editable **BODY**, it started showing a resize-able **SPAN** container. What just fix my problem was a simple one-liner CSS style
**pointer-events: none;** on the inner **SPAN** tag.

```css
min-width: 1.5cm;
display: inline-block;
pointer-events: none;
```

```html
<body content-editable="true">
  <span>Sample Text</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe solved **for you**, but I do not consider this "solved" because you are assuming others do not wish to allow users to click on the contenteditable, but disabling it, when in fact, in many cases, you still want to allow clicking.

Comment: Also, an ***exact same** answer was written here years before yours... (by *Kevin Lee*)

Comment: FYI, kevin Lee suggested to add pointer-events: none on parent <DIV> element (not on the child <span>) which in my case, didn't resolve the problem. Also, if we changes the property of the child, you can still keep it clickable using the click event on the parent <DIV>

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with CKEditor 4.4.7 in IE11. As a workaround, I save the current dimensions of an element on "mousedown" and set the "min-width", "max-width", "min-height" and "max-height" style properties to it's current dimensions. By that the element will be displayed in it's original size during resize. On "mouseup" I restore the style properties of the modified element. Here is my code:

```
$('textarea').ckeditor().on('instanceReady.ckeditor', function(event, editor) {
    var $doc = $(editor.document.$);
    $doc.on("mousedown", "table,img", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var widthAttrValue = $this.attr("width");
        if (widthAttrValue) {
            $this.data("widthAttrValue", widthAttrValue);
        }
        var widthStyleValue = this.style.width;
        if (widthStyleValue) {
            $this.data("widthStyleValue", widthStyleValue);
        }
        var width = widthStyleValue || widthAttrValue || String($this.width())+"px";
        var height = this.style.height || $this.attr("height") || String($this.height())+"px";
        $this.css({
            "min-width": width,
            "max-width": width,
            "min-height": height,
            "max-height": height,                                       
        });
        $doc.data("mouseDownElem",$this);
    }).on("mouseup", function() {
        var $elem = $doc.data("mouseDownElem");
        if ($elem) {
            $elem.removeAttr("height").css("height","");
            var widthAttrValue = $elem.data("widthAttrValue");
            if (widthAttrValue) {
                $elem.attr("width", widthAttrValue);
                $elem.removeData("widthAttrValue");
            } else {
                $elem.removeAttr("width");
            }
            var widthStyleValue = $elem.data("widthStyleValue");
            if (widthStyleValue) {                                      
                $elem.removeData("widthStyleValue");
            } 
            $elem.css({
                "min-width":"",
                "max-width":"",
                "min-height":"",
                "max-height":"",
                "width": widthStyleValue || ""
            });
            if (!$.trim($elem.attr("style"))) {
                $elem.removeAttr("style");
            }
            $doc.removeData("mouseDownElem");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this problem. For me this would only happen when the `contenteditable` element was empty and the resize handles would disappear when there was content so I created the following CSS only solution to go about this:

```
[contenteditable]:empty:after {
  content: " ";
}
```

The idea behind the solution is whenever the `contenteditable` field is empty it applies a blank space pseudo element thus removing the resize tags from showing up when the user selects the `contenteditable` field. Once the user has entered anything then the pseudo element disappears.

Note, because of the use of pseudo elements, this fix only works on IE9 and up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I put CSS rules for the max-width onto all child elements within the contenteditable. Removing it or restricting it to images did the trick.

```
[contenteditable] * { max-width: 100%; } // causes the issue
[contenteditable] img { max-width: 100%; } // works fine for me
```

Make sure that no `<p>` elements are affected by the max-width property.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing anyone else recommended here or in other threads really worked for me, but I solved it by doing:

```
[contenteditable="true"] p:empty {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This way the resize boxes disappeared, but I could still set my cursor below or in the P blocks to edit them.