# IE 11: how to hide resizeable border of editable content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tinymce, internet-explorer-11

I am using a custom dropdown in a richtext editor(Tinymce). And in IE11, there is a resizeable border of the content like this:

[image]

How to hide this border?

P.S: outline:0 & border: 0 is not working

Comment: You can see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864047/ie-how-to-disable-elements-selection-and-resizing-in-contenteditable-div