# How to hide resizeable border of editable content?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11

*Note: I'm aware of this question: [How to disable elements selection and resizing in contenteditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21864047/10815568) . This question is slightly different.*

I'm current using Kendo UI Editor. When I'm using IE 11. There's an resizable border of the content like this:

[Here's the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46fk8.png)

How to hide the border? I tried putting ***border: none;*** on my css. ***I even search about this issue but it keeps redirecting me into other Editor.***

Here's the sample code: (try to use IE 11 to see the issue)
https://dojo.telerik.com/AJOXeGAb

[this is my IE version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46fk8.png)

Comment: I've used the demo from the official website:https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/index I runned it on IE but could not reproduce your problem. Could you share your related code so that it will be better to help with you?(You could share a fiddle or in https://dojo.telerik.com/)

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/AJuRUVoW @JeniferJiang here is the sample code try to run it on IE.

Comment: Is this issue still occurring? I'm unable to reproduce it in IE11 using your link.

Comment: @rawnewdlz yes it is, this is the updated link for the demo - https://dojo.telerik.com/AJOXeGAb

Comment: does it work when you apply !important to it just to test it? If it is working, than you have to increase your specificity. More infos here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: This has to do with IE and "hasLayout". There appears to be no real solution from what I've found in researching this interesting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```html
border: 0px;
```