# How to remove SharePoint RTE.Canvas in IE11 when in editing mode

Tags: javascript, canvas, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I try to edit the SharePoint Rich Text Editor box using IE11, But IE is automatically group the Div using `RTE.Canvas` based on the CSS. But `RTE.Canvas` grouping is not working in chrome. Please check the image below.

[image]

I don't want this box canvas in IE when i edit the SharePoint RTE, compare to chrome it doesn't shown.

I try to hide this box in IE but it doesn't work,
The Methods i follow.

```
<script>
        //<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".ms-rtestate-write").bind('paste', function(e) {
                    var text = $(this).html();
                    $(this).html(text.replace( /<\s*span.*?>/gi,"").replace( /<\s*\/\s*span\s*.*?>/gi,""));
                });
            });
        //]]>
        </script>
```

After using the above script, it doesn't affect the `RTE.Canvas`

```
RTE.Canvas = null
```

It's affecting entire canvas.

**I don't want the highlighted box in IE when edit the SharePoint RTE, please help me to resolve canvas issue.**

Answer (score 0):

By placing a contenteditable DIV within a non contenteditable DIV the handles do not appear in IE or FF but you can still edit the content

Ex.

```
<div class="outerContainer" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="innerContainer" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Your can read further here:
[How to Remove Resize handles and border of div with contentEditable and size style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772342/how-to-remove-resize-handles-and-border-of-div-with-contenteditable-and-size-sty][1])

Comment: It's not related to the Content Editable, its related to SharePoint RTE control

Comment: I would like to see the html from
`var text = $(this).html();`