# How to remove DIV selection on click of DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Note:** i tired all questions & answer related this topic. **Like This and i tried related questions and try to solve it but not success.**

See My Code i append div `<div class="clsElements" style="display: block;" contenteditable="true">0</div>` into `clsDiv`.
worked fine . but i click on new div  then it selects div in **Internet Explorer**

**Internet Explorer** 
[image]

**Chrome & Firefox** 
[image]

**Live Demo** [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ba31xoqy/)

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: IE 11.0 version

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926525/removing-resize-handlers-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: @Alexis i also tried . but its not working

Comment: But it's the same question :c

Comment: I don't see the behavior in IE11 in your jsfiddle example.