# Getting resize handlers in IE on elements when i apply display as flex

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ckeditor, contenteditable

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="display:flex">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

This adds ugly resize border on the P tag. I want to keep this field editable. I don't want to disable it using mscontrolselect event
Any solution?

Comment: Related (doesn't appear to solve the issue, but it's been asked before) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926525/removing-resize-handlers-on-contenteditable-div  Edit: *many* times before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=contenteditable+resize+handles

Comment: Why do you add `display:flex`? If you remove this style, the field is still editable. Or you can remove `<p>` tag around the text, then the resize border will disappear. Besides these two ways, it seems there's no other ways to get rid of the resize border.